# Wikipedia Dump available on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-s3, data-mining, wikipedia-api

Would like to know if there are there any publicly available s3 buckets that contain data from Wikipedia ?

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. It's a valid question , an AWS blog says it's available when searched in the registry it's not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia is **not** available as a public dataset on Amazon S3.

See:

- [Open Data on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/opendata/)
- [Registry of Open Data on AWS](https://registry.opendata.aws/)